# Jquery: How do i convert 1111-yyyy-mm-dd into 1111-mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

Using jquery/Javascript how can i convert  a value with date  `1111-2016-10-26` INTO `1111 - 10/26/2016` format ?

i tried below code but it did not helped.

```
var date = new Date('2010-10-11');
alert((date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' +  date.getFullYear());
```

Comment: what's the issue? What do you mean for numbers is a little tricky?

Comment: @James update my question. Can anyone please help me to know the reason behind -5 negative ratings?, Just asked to try NOT to repeat the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to convert without any date validations you can do it with string functions. Or if you want to use date functions, apply it only to that part of the string after splitting the string. Nothing fancy.

Use normal Date constructor `(year,[month,[date...]])` when creating Date objects, passing non-standard formats is not recommended as the implementations are browser dependant.

```js
var string = "1111-2016-10-26";
var a = string.split('-');
var number = a[0];
var date = a[2] + '/' + a[3] + '/' + a[1];
console.log(number + '-' + date);
```

```js
var string = '1111-2010-10-11';
var a = string.split('-').map(Number);
var date = new Date(a[1], a[2] - 1, a[3]);
var dateString = ((date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' +  date.getFullYear());

console.log(a[0]+ '-' + dateString);
```

Comment: Good answer, but the `.map(Number)` bit is redundant in the second code snippet. ;-)

Comment: @RobG The intention was to convert strings to numbers before using it in Date constructor. Without that I guess we could do `+a[1]`?

Comment: There is no need to convert strings to numbers when passing more than one argument, they will be converted to Number anyway (see [*ECMA-262 §20.3.2.1 step 3*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date-year-month-date-hours-minutes-seconds-ms).